# Parsing/Printing depending on char length in Python; only 98% on CodeEval

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout

So I'm working through a CodeEval problem right now, and, for some reason, I can't get past a 98/100 score.

Here's a link to the challenge on CodeEval:

https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/167/

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

zeefile = open(sys.argv[1])

for line in zeefile:
    if len(line) <= 55:
       sys.stdout.write(line)
    elif len(line) > 55:
        line = line[:40].rsplit(" ", 1)[0]
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        sys.stdout.write('... <Read More> \n')
```

I've beaten my head against this wall for a several hours, even with a few devs far more talented than I'll ever be.

We're perplexed, to say the least. Ultimately, it's not a big deal, but I'd like to know if there's something being missed here so I can learn from it.

I've checked the code over and over, I've checked the input, I've checked the output...I can't find any inconsistency, or anything that suggests I'm missing that last 2% of a successful solution.

Any idea what we're missing as to why this isn't coming back as a 100% legit solution to the problem? I'm hoping some fresh eyes and sharp minds can help me out on this one! Thank you very much!

Comment: In the code you display there's an extra space before the newline.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned that (I should have originally), because I've actually tried with and without that extra space and, without the extra space, it gives me a 97/100 instead of 98/100. It makes no sense, as it seems to prefer it. Could it be the "\n", or more generally, how I'm printing?

Comment: The instructions are unclear. The challenge is apparently to read the question-writer's mind about how to deal with spaces. The only arbitrary thing I might try is to compress multiple spaces in the line. I'm pulling that out of a hat (or somewhere), but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Understood @ooga, I really appreciate you taking a look; I'll just leave it at this then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code (100% on Code Eval):

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as in_f:
    for line in in_f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 55:
            line = "{0}... <Read More>".format(line[:40].rsplit(" ", 1)[0].rstrip())
        sys.stdout.write("{0}\n".format(line))
```

I used this file:

```
Tom exhibited.
Amy Lawrence was proud and glad, and she tried to make Tom see it in her face - but he wouldn't look.
Tom was tugging at a button-hole and looking sheepish.
Two thousand verses is a great many - very, very great many.
Tom's mouth watered for the apple, but he stuck to his work.
```

and got the following output:

```
Tom exhibited.
Amy Lawrence was proud and glad, and... <Read More>
Tom was tugging at a button-hole and looking sheepish.
Two thousand verses is a great many -... <Read More>
Tom's mouth watered for the apple, but... <Read More>
```

[image: Code Eval Score]

Comment: Wow, that's awesome; thanks so much @Incognos ! So it looks like you've cleaned it up with how you open and loop (no double-check with if/elif; NICE!), while also using .format() to add in the necessary string. Any conceptual critique you'd be willing to provide a newbie? Thanks again!

Comment: not sure about conceptual critiques, but constructively, I would say that I refined the above over multiple iteration. Meaning, my experience with coding, help me reduce it to this. I think your code is good for a self professed newbie. Keep at it and you will be answering the questions :)